# How to use ng-init with an object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I have a dropdown whose value is an object. The html code is as follows.

```
<div class="form-group">  
    <label>Goal<span class="red-ast">*</span></label><br />   
    <select ng-change="setgoal(goals)" ng-model="goals" ng-init="goals={{oldGoal}}" class="form-control b-rad3">      
    <option ng-repeat="goal in allgoals" value="{{goal}}">{{goal.title}}</option>    
    </select>    
</div>
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
$scope.allgoals = [
    0 => {
        title : "ABC",
        icon : "icon1.jpg",
        id : 01
    },
    1 => {
        title : "DEF",
        icon : "icon2.jpg",
        id : 02
    },
    2 => {
        title : "GHI",
        icon : "icon3.jpg",
        id : 03
    }

]

$scope.oldGoal = {
        title : "DEF",
        icon : "icon2.jpg",
        id : 02
    };
```

It will show me a dropdown of ABC, DEF, GHI. Its fine but I want that DEF will be preselected in dropdown. If I am doing in this manner it is giving me some parsing error. Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Comment: `[ 0 => { ...` syntax does not look correct. Do you mean `[{...}, {...}]`?

Comment: @uzbekjon Ya I mean [{...}, {...}].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Iwyf8Ct0KNqXGSGpzCda?p=preview)

Just use `ng-selected="c.title==oldGoal.title"`.

```
<option ng-selected="c.title==oldGoal.title" ng-repeat="c in allgoals">{{c.title}}</option>
```

**Update:**

[Here is the updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yT5wQka7Da8vuB2061d0?p=preview). Please check and let me know.

Comment: there is an error in your code it is selecting only the last one.

Comment: In your plnkr it's working fine but in my code it is not working. I am unable to understand why it is not working. When I do inspect element on my dropdown it is showing 'selected="selected" ' for that particular value which shows your logic is correct but still in drop down it is not showing .

Comment: If you remove `ng-model="goals"`, it should work. [http://plnkr.co/edit/sumydZvUqT7krvjY2IQN?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/sumydZvUqT7krvjY2IQN?p=preview)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108241/discussion-between-user3542450-and-khalid-hussain).